# Does posix_memalign() sets the pointer to NULL on fail?

Tags: c

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

allocate `size` bytes aligned on `alignment`. It returns 0 on success and errno on fail.

**Is the `*memptr` set to 0 on fail?**

Comment: The lack of specification implies that this is unspecified/undefined behaviour.  Thus you shouldn't rely on any particular behaviour.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks. Like you said, I didn't find it in the man pages. So I think I should set *memptr to NULL manually when posix_memalign fails.

Comment: An implementation is available [here](https://code.google.com/p/senol/source/browse/trunk/code/flibc/malloc/posix_memalign.c) for example, that particular implementation does not touch *memptr on failure (although nothing in the specification would _prevent_ it from doing that).

Answer (score 2):

It may do, but it is not guaranteed to.

See [the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_memalign.html) where it merely says:

> Upon successful completion, `posix_memalign()` shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

It says nothing about what happens to `*memptr` on error, so my read would be that its state is undefined. Obviously the two most sane behaviours would be 0, or leave it as it is, but you cannot rely on that.